# HTML range input manually loose mouse event

Tags: javascript, input, range, mouseevent, element

I have a classic HTML range input element and I want it to "loose" the mouse event (I think this is a wrong expression but I can only explain it this way) if the user moves the slider below 80.

So, the moment the slider value is below 80, so it will be 79 with step 1 (no less), the element will loose the mouse event, **as if the user had just clicked up**. But I want this to happen with js or jQuery by the system.

It may be simple but it will be a powerfull tool to me.

thanks!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbngbxfq/)

```
$('#myRange').on("input", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();  
    if(val < 80){
        // here goes the code I am looking for
    } 
});
```

Comment: `$('#myRange').prop("readOnly",true);`

Comment: ok that's a good command. but I want to set the readOnly to false after the element has lost the mouse event. is this : http://jsfiddle.net/sbngbxfq/1/ a good way to do that ?

Comment: @vinayakj please make your comment answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starter, you can make the field as readonly.

```
$('#myRange').prop("readOnly",true);
```

Example

```
$('#myRange').on("input", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();  
    if(val < 80){
        $('#myRange').prop("readOnly",true);
           } 

})
.on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(){
      $('#myRange').prop("readOnly",true);
    },
    function(){
      $('#myRange').prop("readOnly",false);
    });
```